# How to make Krusader to show file name with extensions?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, krusader

Are there any settings that can make Krusader show file name with extensions after it (instead of just show file name and the extension is in a separate column)?

Having examined each and every setting items in all windows and tabs of Konfigurator, I simply can not find the way to do it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Names with the extension:

- By using the Brief View.
- With the Detailed View - Right click the Krusader Name/Ext/Size/... column and disable the extension column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice to have the ability to display filenames including the extensions and still have the Ext column (to be able to sort by extension).

Comment: After Krusader is restarted *Ext* column in set back to enabled. Any idea how to make this setting permanent?